# Opening file, removing punctuation and appending in another file in c++

Tags: c++

Okay so going straight to the point: I'm working on the main.cpp of my project, and I want to open an article (prototype.txt), remove punctuation from each line and append them to another .txt file (example.txt).

I've written the code below, and something is wrong: when I open the example.txt, the file is empty(no lines have been appended). Any idea where my error is? Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include "1.h"
#include "2.h"
#include "3.h"

using namespace std;
using std::string;

int main()
{
    std::ifstream file("prototype.txt");
    std::string linestr;
    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open ("example.txt");


    if(file.is_open() && myfile.is_open())
    {

            while (std::getline(file, linestr))                             //"while" loop for each text 
                                                                            //line
            {
                    for (int i = 0, len = linestr.size(); i < len; i++)     //"for" loop
                    {                                                       //to remove
                        if (ispunct(linestr[i]))                            //punctuation
                        {
                            linestr.erase(i--, 1);
                            len = linestr.size();
                        }
                    }

                    myfile.open ("example.txt",  std::ios_base::app); // append instead of overwrite
                    myfile << linestr << endl;

            }
            myfile.close();

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I would like to advise you to use a debugger

Comment: FYI -- There is no need for that `for` loop.  That entire `for` loop could be just `linestr.erase(std::remove_if(linestr.begin(), linestr.end(), [](char ch){return std::is_punct(ch);}), linestr.end());`.

Comment: ```myfile.open ("example.txt",  std::ios_base::app); // append instead of overwrite``` is opening the file in a loop. Instead, you should open it once and close once as well.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I've tried this, but I'm getting errors like: 'remove if' is not a member of std.

Comment: ***but I'm getting errors like: 'remove if' is not a member of std.*** That means you need to include a header.  `#include <algorithm>` When I don't know I google it and in less than a minute I have the answer on what header to use. And yes after 25+ years of c++ there are times when I still need to google for something like this.

Comment: You are correct. I googled it a couple of times but wasn't getting the answer I wanted. Looks like it was in front of me the whole time

Answer (score 1):

You need to open your file only once, not for each line, also you close files when all is done:

```
int main()
{
    std::string linestr = "";

    std::ifstream file("prototype.txt");
    std::ofstream myfile("example.txt", std::ios_base::app);

    if (file.is_open() && myfile.is_open())
    {
        while (std::getline(file, linestr))
        {
            for (std::size_t pos = linestr.find('.'); pos != string::npos; pos = linestr.find('.'))
            {
                linestr.erase(pos, 1);
            }

            myfile << linestr << endl;
        }
    }

    myfile.close();
    file.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. I tried to to do this to my code, but still the example.txt is empty and no lines have been appended.

Comment: I've edited my answer with new loop, as suggested by missing commentator

Comment: I also edited it with the new loop but still the .txt file is empty and I don't why this is happening

Comment: I see, I made a new edit that resolves the problem with empty output file. please try again!

Comment: This time it does seem to work, although just for the dots "."  Still, nice job, thanks


Edit: I used the`linestr.erase(std::remove_if(linestr.begin(), linestr.end(), [](char ch){return std::is_punct(ch);}), linestr.end());` instead of your `for` loop which now removes every punctuation mark.

Answer (score 0):

Use the standard library. That's what it's for. [`std::copy_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) is exactly what you need. First get the code working by copying between strings (much easier to debug):

```
#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <fstream>

struct should_copy {
    bool operator()(char c1) {
        return !std::ispunct(c1);
    }
};

template <class InIt, class OutIt>
void copy_without_punctuation(InIt first, InIt last, OutIt dest) {
    std::copy_if(first, last, dest, should_copy());
}

int main() {
    std::string input("abc.de,f");
    std::string output;
    copy_without_punctuation(std::begin(input),
        std::end(input),
        std::back_inserter(output));
    std::cout << input << '\n';
    std::cout << output << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Then switch to stream iterators that manage the files:

```
int main() {
    std::ifstream input("prototype.txt");
    std::ofstream output("example.txt");
    copy_without_punctuation(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(input),
        std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(),
        std::ostreambuf_iterator<char>(output));
    return 0;
}
```